# Custom HTML - Rally TreeGrid

Tags: javascript, rally

Hello i am receiving an error from the code below, and not sure why because i thought i was defining it. I want to make sure my code is working properly before i add complexity to the report.

```
 launch: function() {   
     this._createGrid(); 
 },

 _createGrid: function() {
     Ext.create('Rally.data.wsapi.TreeStoreBuilder').build({
         models: ['PortfolioItem/Initiative'],
         autoLoad: true,
         enableHierarchy: true
     }).then({
         success: function(store) {
             var myGrid = Ext.create('Ext.Container', {
                 items: [{
                     xtype: 'rallytreegrid',
                     columnCfgs: ['Name', 'Owner'],
                     store: store
                 }],
                 renderTo: Ext.getBody()
             });
        }
    });
    this.add(myGrid);
},

});
```

"Error: success callback for Deferred transformed result of Deferred transformed result of Deferred threw: ReferenceError: myGrid is not defined"

I am new to this so any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: The code does work, but wanted to figure out the reasoning of the error before moving forward

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You issue you're running into is probably due to some confusion in how components and containers behave in ExtJS combined with the `this` scoping issue mentioned in the answer above.

Here's how I would write it:

```
_createGrid: function() {
    Ext.create('Rally.data.wsapi.TreeStoreBuilder').build({
        models: ['PortfolioItem/Initiative'],
        autoLoad: true,
        enableHierarchy: true
    }).then({
        success: function(store) {
            //The app class is already a container, so you can just
            //directly add the grid to it
            this.add({
                xtype: 'rallytreegrid',
                itemId: 'myGrid',
                columnCfgs: ['Name', 'Owner'],
                store: store
            });
        },
        scope: this //make sure the success handler executes in correct scope
    });
}
```

You also don't need to feel like you need to keep a `myGrid` reference around since you can always find it using the built-in component querying feature of ExtJS:

```
var myGrid = this.down('#myGrid');
```

Answer (score 0):

You're defining `myGrid` inside of the `success` function scope, then trying to use it at the end of the `_createGrid` function, where it is `undefined`. I assume you're trying to do it that way because `this` is not bound correctly inside the `success` function. Try this instead:

```
_createGrid: function() {
     var self = this;
     Ext.create('Rally.data.wsapi.TreeStoreBuilder').build({
         models: ['PortfolioItem/Initiative'],
         autoLoad: true,
         enableHierarchy: true
     }).then({
         success: function(store) {
             var myGrid = Ext.create('Ext.Container', {
                 items: [{
                     xtype: 'rallytreegrid',
                     columnCfgs: ['Name', 'Owner'],
                     store: store
                 }],
                 renderTo: Ext.getBody()
             });
             self.add(myGrid);
        }
    });
},
```